# How to count duplicated last columns without removing them?

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing

I have a file that contains 4 columns. I want to compare the last three columns and count how many times they occur without deleting any of the lines. I just want the count to be present in front of each line.

My file looks like this:

```
ID-jacob  4.0  6.0  42.0  
ID-elsa   5.0  8.0  45.0  
ID-fred   4.0  6.0  42.0  
ID-gerard 6.0  8.0  20.0  
ID-trudy  5.0  8.0  45.0  
ID-tessa  4.0  6.0  42.0
```

My desired outcome is:

```
3 ID-jacob  4.0  6.0  42.0  
2 ID-elsa   5.0  8.0  45.0  
3 ID-fred   4.0  6.0  42.0  
1 ID-gerard 6.0  8.0  20.0  
2 ID-trudy  5.0  8.0  45.0  
3 ID-tessa  4.0  6.0  42.0
```

I tried to use sort and uniq, but this only gives me the first line per duplicate lines:

```
cat file | sort -k2,4 | uniq -c -f1 > outputfile
```

Comment: The problem you are going to have is: how can it know to output `3` in front of the `ID-jacob` line at which point it doesn't know how many more lines with the same value will come in the future. As such, your solution cannot be a filter, it has to read the whole file first or at least arbitrarily large chunks of it.

Comment: How about creating a temporary file with "uniq -c -f1" that contains the count, an ID of one duplicate and the three numbers. Then paste its first column in front of the initial file if column 3,4, and 5 match with column 2,3, and 4 of the initial file? That should work right? But I don't know how to do this either..

Comment: you will need to read this set of lines at least 2 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run into trouble storing large files in memory, this is slightly better as it only stores matching lines, after sort has done the heavy lifting of putting the lines in order.

```
# Input must be sorted first, then we only need to keep matching lines in memory
# Once we reach a non-matching line we print the lines in memory, prefixed by count
# with awk, variables are unset to begin with so, we can get away without explicitly initializing
{ # S2, S3, S4 are saved field values
  if($2 == S2 && $3 == S3 && $4 == S4) {
    # if fields 2,3,4 are same as last, save line in array, increment count
    line[count++] = $0;
  } else {
    # new line with fields 2, 3, 4 different
    # print stored lines, prefixed by the count
    for(i in line) {
      print count, line[i];
    }
    # reset counter and array
    count=0;
    delete line;
    # save this line in array, increment count
    line[count++] = $0;
  }

  # store field values to compare with next line read
  S2 = $2; S3 = $3; S4 = $4;
}
END{ # on EOF we still have saved lines in array, print last lines
    for(i in line) {
      print count, line[i];
    }
}
```

It is customary to save `awk` scripts in a file.
You could use this along the lines of
`sort -k2,4 file | awk -f script`

```
3 ID-fred   4.0  6.0  42.0  
3 ID-jacob  4.0  6.0  42.0  
3 ID-tessa  4.0  6.0  42.0
2 ID-elsa   5.0  8.0  45.0  
2 ID-trudy  5.0  8.0  45.0  
1 ID-gerard 6.0  8.0  20.0
```

Answer (score 3):

It might help:

```
awk '{ pop[$1] = $2" "$3" "$4; x[$2" "$3" "$4]++; } END { for (name in pop) { if (pop[name] in x) { print x[pop[name]], name, pop[name]; } } }' file
```

It creates two arrays pop and x. In pop we have keys from column1 and value=colum2" "column3" "column4, in array x we have keys values from array pop and values counting repetitions. In final loop we check for each name in array pop value in array x.
It does no preserve your order.

Comment: Great! It seems to work. Can you explain to me what the code does in parts? Would be very helpful for understanding.

Comment: but this does not keep your order. It create too arrays pop and x. In pop we have keys from column1 and value=colum2" "column3" "column4, in x we have keys values from pop and values counting repetitions. In final loop we check for each name in array pop value in array x.

Comment: you can learn more with `man awk`

Comment: Keeping the order of lines is not necessary, as long as the lines stay intact, so the numbers in column 2,3, and 4, will not be scrambled.

Comment: @taliezin Please [Edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/191164/edit) your answer and add [your explanation in your comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191155/count-duplicate-lines-without-removing-them#comment319606_191164) in body of answer. thanks